# Correct usage of IndexOf in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, indexof

I've got a simple JavaScript statement that reads a string and fires off a URL based of what it contains but I'm not sure if I've used `IndexOf` correctly so I just wanted to check.

Here is my code snippet:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 

var mc_u1 = "somevariable";

if (mc_u1.indexOf("1|Accept") > 0) {
document.writeln("<img src=\"https://www.someurl1.com\">");
}

if (mc_u1.indexOf("1|Refer") > 0) {
document.writeln("<img src=\"https://www.someurl2.com\">");

}

if (mc_u1.indexOf("2|Accept") > 0) {
document.writeln("<img src=\"https://www.someurl3.com\">");

}

if (mc_u1.indexOf("2|Refer") > 0) {
document.writeln("<img src=\"www.someurl4.com\">");

}

</script>
```

As you can see from the code above, what I'm trying to do is based on the contents of the variable `mc_u1` fire off a URL (which are different though I've just masked them for obvious reasons).

My question is, if the `mc_u1` variable begins with say `1|Accept` should I be using `> -1` in the Javascript Statement or `> 0`?

Hope this is making sense!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [**MDN**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf):

> `string.indexOf(searchValue[, fromIndex])`
>
> Returns the index within the calling `String` object of the first
>   occurrence of the specified value, starting the search at `fromIndex`,
>   returns `-1` if the value is not found.

So in order to check if your variable starts with `"1|Accept"` you should check if `indexOf` returns `0`.

Comment: Far better to reference the ECMAScipt standard for [indexOf](http://es5.github.com/#x15.4.4.14) rather than MDN for standard language features. MDN is a wiki and not an authority, though it is good for examples sometimes.

Answer (score 3):

0 is the index of the first letter, so if your substring appears at the beginning of the string, `> 0` will not match.  So use `> -1` for anywhere in the string and `== 0` for always at the start of the string.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `== 0` since at the beginning, the index will be 0

Answer (score 0):

`mc_u1.indexOf("1|Accept") > 0` will also be true if the string only contains substring somewhere.
It will be `-1` if the substring wasn't found.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf